# Wiring to ceiling fan/light

Tags: switch, fans

[image]I recently purchased an older home. In the living room, it has a ceiling fan with light kit. It has a single pole switch (no ground) controlling the power to the fan/light. I'm replacing the switch with a rocker. There are 3 wires - red, black & white. When testing, the black is hot as one would assume, I can only assume white is common but what is the red? Is this the switched leg? If so where would the common terminate in this set-up. Next question, if I want to come off of this line and wire a small LED that is always hot (has a motion sensor) I assume I can come off the black and even when light/fan is off, I still have power to LED light? 120V when testing from white & black. No voltage any other combination so no power when running red & black to switch. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The red, black, and white wires are the house wiring? Does the switch box contain only these three wires--one each of red, black and white?

Comment: Do not assume the white is neutral/common.  Plain/simple(non smart) do not use neutral, but do use white as hot and black/red as switch hot.  Newer code requires neutral to be in the box if used or not, if not used then it is capped off.  Add pictures on how the old switch is wired(breaker off, wires on switch).

Comment: Did the original switch control both the light and the fan in unison? Is the original switch still in place or at least is it connected? If so, how is or was it connected to the original switch?

Comment: I have never heard of anyone rigging up a motion sensor to a ceiling fan with light. Did you want the motion sensor to only turn on the light?

Comment: You are replacing a single pole switch with a rocker...?  It's the same thing, why is there a problem?

Comment: You've got the switch out of the outlet box, take a couple of clear, focused, well lit pictures of exactly what the existing wiring looks like, showing how the wires come off the switch and how they go into the box to leave it. [Edit] these into your question. That will show us _exactly_ what's going on so we can get you a good, correct answer.

Comment: You probably have enough wires to enable separate control of the fan and light. If you do, there are double switches you can put in place of the single switch (e.g., Leviton 5634).  This would not prevent putting in a motion detector.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: To clarify; 3 wires coming out of the wall (R,B,W). R was capped off. Originally had single pole, 2 way toggle. Replaced with single pole, 2 way paddle. When purchased toggle switch controlled both fan & light. Wanting to continue circuit to a small led motion sensor light & a duplex outlet. Motion sensor is integral to the light so will only be used on the light, just need to run a continuous hot to the light. Want outlet to be continuously hot as well. Thinking I'll need a 3 way switch so I can use the load side to run to the outlet & light just didn't know what the R wire was.

Comment: Currently, if I connect B & W to a 2 way switch, I can control the fan & light together (I don't need separate switches). I was hoping I could use a 3 way switch and continue the load side downstream providing constant load to the outlet & light but not sure this will work or how to do it.